SSE client exception "java.io.IOException: chunked transfer encoding, state: READING_DATA" or "READING_LENGTH"
We tried to transfer some data from server to client, but saw this error. Any idea why and how to fix it?
Caused by: java.io.IOException: chunked transfer encoding, state: READING_DATA
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils.wrapWithExtraDetail(Utils.java:351)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$BodyReader.onReadError(Http1Response.java:760)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver.checkForErrors(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:302)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver.flush(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:268)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:157)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:305)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:274)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver.onReadError(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:511)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver$Http1TubeSubscriber.onComplete(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:596)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$DelegateWrapper.onComplete(SSLTube.java:276)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.complete(SSLTube.java:440)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.onComplete(SSLTube.java:541)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.checkCompletion(SubscriberWrapper.java:472)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run1(SubscriberWrapper.java:334)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run(SubscriberWrapper.java:259)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:303)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:256)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.outgoing(SubscriberWrapper.java:232)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:513)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:268)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230)
... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: EOF reached while reading
... 21 common frames omitted
